# Asp.net MVC NavBar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have this error in the navbar in asp.net mvc

[image]

And this id my code

```
                <li class="nav-item  nav-link" role="presentation">

                    <a class="nav-link" @Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers") />

                </li>
```

So why this character come />

The close for the

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Html.ActionLink` inside anchor tag, which is totally wrong:

```
<a class="nav-link" @Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers") />
```

I suggest you to use `ActionLink` helper alone with `@class` attribute instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })
```

Or use `@Url.Action` with anchor tag:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Customers")">Customers</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line:

```
<a class="nav-link" @Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers") />
```

to

```
<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Customers")">Customers</a>
```

or:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Customers", "Index", "Customers", null, new {@class = "nav-link"})
```

This is because `@Html.ActionLink()` generates the entire anchor (`<a>`) element whereas `@Url.Action()` just generates the URL for the route, you need to do one or the other.